# Only return parameters if they are not empty

Tags: javascript, ember.js, constants

I have a method to generate filters like below:

```
_generateFilters() {
    const status = get(this, 'controller.status');
    const type = get(this, 'controller.type');
    const name = get(this, 'controller.name');

    const statusFilter = isEmpty(status) ? [] : generateFilter(status);
    const typeFilter = isEmpty(type) ? [] : generateFilter(type);
    const nameFilter = isEmpty(name) ? [] : generateFilter(name);

    return {
       statusFilter,
       typeFilter,
       nameFilter,
    };
}
```

For now it will return all parameters, but I want to return the parameters only with not empty value. like if status is empty, type and name is non empty, then return { tyepFilter, nameFilter }. 
Does someone know how to do it in this method? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps check if it's equal to null or undefined?

Answer (score 1):

You can start with an empty Object and just add what needs to be added:

```
_generateFilters() {
    const status = get(this, 'controller.status');
    const type = get(this, 'controller.type');
    const name = get(this, 'controller.name');

    const res = {};

    !isEmpty(status) && (res.statusFilter = generateFilter(status));
    !isEmpty(type) && (res.typeFilter = generateFilter(type));
    !isEmpty(name) && (res.nameFilter = generateFilter(name));

    return res;
}
```

If you're not familiar with that way of using `&&`:

```
!isEmpty(status) && (res.statusFilter = generateFilter(status));
```

It's equivalent to:

```
if (!isEmpty(status)) { res.statusFilter = generateFilter(status); }
```

It works with `&&` thanks to *short-circuit evaluation*: When you chain conditions with `&&`, as soon as one of these conditions is falsy, the rest is not executed. Hence, you won't add the property to the result if `!isEmpty()` returns `false`

Comment: Are you sure the format of `short-circuit evaluation` is correct, because I get a mistake ?

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine-Aladdin Woops, you're right, I forgot to add parentheses around the `res.x = ...` statements. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem with [`@computed.collect`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.18/classes/@ember%2Fobject%2Fcomputed/methods/collect?anchor=collect) and [`@computed.filter`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.18/classes/@ember%2Fobject%2Fcomputed/methods/filter?anchor=filter):

```js
export default class MyFilterComponent extends Component {
  @computed.collect('controller.{status,name,type}') parameters;
  @computed.filter('parameters', (parameter) => parameter) validParams;

  _generateFilters() {
    return this.validParams;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could simplify the brace expansion and just use `@computed.filter` and use the `isEmpty` helper to guard against empty strings like `''` and `' '`:

```js
import {computed} from '@ember/object';
import {isEmpty} from '@ember/utils';

export default class MyFilterComponent extends Component {
  @computed.filter('controller.{status,name,type}', (parameter) => isEmpty(parameter)) validParams;

  _generateFilters() {
    return this.validParams;
  }
}
```